# Bitbucket CI/CD Deployment Issue for Non-Default Branch (e.g., 'QA') to EC2 Instance

Tags: bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm facing an issue while setting up a Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline to deploy my Laravel application to an EC2 instance. My goal is to configure the pipeline to deploy the 'release/QA' branch, which is not the default branch. I've followed several tutorials and examples, but I'm encountering challenges specific to deploying a non-default branch. Here's a breakdown of my setup:

My Laravel project is hosted on Bitbucket.
I have created a separate branch named 'release/QA' for testing purposes.
My EC2 instance is up and running, and I have SSH access to it.
I've created an SSH key pair and added the public key to the EC2 instance's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.
I've set up a .bitbucket-pipelines.yml configuration file in my project's root directory.but that is created **master** branch.i want create cicd to release/QA branch.

Here's a simplified version of my .bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
`image: php:7.2

pipelines:
  branches:
    release/QA:
      - step:
         name: release/QA
         caches:
          - composer
         script :
          - yum update
          - ssh root@ip-170-30-6-60 'bash s' < execute.sh `
```

can you explain how to configure release/QA branch and if bitbucket-pipelines.yml is created master branch is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You can review my gist for how to setup/pull push for laravel application. you can define some additional step to deploy release/QA branch.

For that you can write some step to sh file.

```
cd /var/www/html/project_folder
git fetch  //this will fetch all latest branches and code to current folder
git checkout release/QA  //this will change git branch from master
git pull
```

Here is my gist for pull/push/deploy Laravel application. - https://gist.github.com/jack2jm/10bb459a83ca85f4589a25ea5c345050